# Salt state to create virtualenv for python-3.8 on ubuntu 20

Tags: python-3.x, salt-stack, ubuntu-20.04

The following `repo-install.sls` used to work on ubuntu 16, python 3.5

```
repo-install-dependencies:
    pkg.installed:
        - names:
            - python3-pip
            - python3-venv
            - mercurial
            - git
            - subversion

bin_env:
    virtualenv.managed:
        - name: {{ bin_env }}
        - pip_pkgs: 
            - pip
            - setuptools
        - require:
            - pkg: repo-install-dependencies
        - venv_bin: "/usr/bin/pyvenv"
```

On a new Ubuntu 20 server, I am trying to get the above working using `salt 3002.2`. I know on python 3.8 use of pyvenv is deprecated and it is recommended to use `python3 -m venv <dirname>` to create virtual env.

My question is, how do I set bin_env? Is `virtualenv.managed` still relevant, if yes, how can we make it pick venv in python distribution? Or are we supposed to use custom function, something like the following?

```
bin_env:
    cmd.run:
        - name : python3 -m venv {{ bin_env }}
        - require:
                - pkg: repo-install-dependencies
```